# Foreach loop two unequal array

Tags: php

I know how to loop through equal arrays like this

```
foreach( $codes as $index => $code ) {
   echo 'The Code is '.$code;
   echo 'The Name is '.$names[$index];
}
```

Not sure how to loop through these 2 arrays and still manage to get all values when both arrays have different number of elements.

```
$code = array(R9,R10,R11,R12);

$names = array(Robert,John,Steve,Joe,Eddie,Gotham);
```

Comment: Just loop through them separatly?

Comment: Right .. but thats not what I want to do. I want to run one loop for both arrays. Thanks for trying your best :)

Comment: You're probably best off with two separate loops, because their lengths is different. You can use one loop for the longest one, and then use that to loop through everything, and check if there are more elements in the lesser one (so that you never echo something that isn't there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...how to loop through these 2 arrays and still manage to get all values when both arrays have different number of elements.

You can use `for` loop for this.

The solution is:

- Take length of the longest array as the condition for `for` loop.
- Use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function to check whether the index exists in the particular array or not, and display the element accordingly.

So your code should be like this:

```
$code = array("R9","R10","R11","R12");
$names = array("Robert","John","Steve","Joe","Eddie","Gotham");

$maxLength = count($code) > count($names) ? count($code) : count($names);

for($i = 0; $i < $maxLength; ++$i){
    echo array_key_exists($i, $code) ? 'The Code is '. $code[$i] : "";
    echo array_key_exists($i, $names) ? ' The Name is '. $names[$i] : "";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
The Code is R9 The Name is Robert
The Code is R10 The Name is John
The Code is R11 The Name is Steve
The Code is R12 The Name is Joe
The Name is Eddie
The Name is Gotham
```